# Getting coordinates from random points in polygon and sync it with shapefile in QGIS

Tags: shapefile, qgis, point-in-polygon

In QGIS, I have a shapefile that contains a polygon of administrative boundaries in a country. I need to add six random points inside the polygon.

Can i get the coordinates from random points feature and sync it with my polygons?

Ex: I have US administrative boundaries shapefile that contains `"country_name"` and `"state_name"`. Then, i generate six random points for every states. Afterward, i want an exported *.xlsx* file which contains `"country_name"`, `"state_name"`, `"lat_long_1"`, `"lat_long_2"`, `"lat_long_3"`, `"lat_long_4"`, `"lat_long_5"` ,`"lat_long_6"` which every `"lat_long"` is accordance with its state.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Random Points Inside Polygons' functions under Vector/Research Tools.
After that with created points, you can use 'Connect Attributes by Location' functions under Vector/Data Management Tools.